# How to set table row height in angular with html body

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, angular

`

```js
 <colgroup>
                  <col span="1" style="width: 50%;">
                  <col span="2" style="width: 50%;">
                </colgroup>
                <tr class="others-row">
                  <td class="traverse table-td-height">
                    <p class="others-type">Feature</p>
                  </td>
                  <td class="other-c-table-td table-td-height">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="none">
                      <ng-container *ngIf="!row.reviewed && 
                              !testThreatSource(row.threatSource)">
                        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="row.fromFeature" 
                               (ngModelChange)="onFeatureChange(row)">
                          <mat-option *ngFor="let selected of featureList.name; trackBy: 
                                   trackByFeature"
                            [value]="selected">
                            {{selected}}
                          </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                      </ng-container>
                      <ng-container *ngIf="row.reviewed || 
                             testThreatSource(row.threatSource)">
                        <textarea matInput [ngModel]="row.fromFeature" [readonly]="true" 
                               cdkTextareaAutosize
                          #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize" cdkAutosizeMinRows="1"
                          cdkAutosizeMaxRows="2"></textarea>
                      </ng-container>
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </td> </tr>
```

`[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltncy.png)I want to fix tr size If i get multiple lines inside tr not expand tr height adjust with same table row . in below picture you can see my rows get out of place due to multiple line in row one

Feature
                      
                      
                        
                          
                            
                              
                                {{selected}}

Comment: you forgot the picture :(

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information to clearify what you are asking for.

To get elements in angular you can use `@ViewChild`. Checkout the dokumentation.
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

To manipulate an element from your ts file directly you can use the Renderer2.
https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2